# How can i make the text in my image dynamic on desktop and mobile

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Basically i have this image:

[image: img]

The task is to make the text dynamic so it can be changed and also have it responsive for mobile. I haven't tried anything yet because i am stumped at where to begin.

Comment: I assume you mean the text itself, rather than the container (black background), needs to be "dynamic," as you say - meaning that it will be editable and that it will also respond to screen dimensions. If that's the case, you'll have to define exactly how the image is to be handled: Will it always have the same exact size or proportions regardless of screen size? Or will some amount of cropping or re-sizing be permitted? IOW, you'll have to define the container and the image, in relation to each other, before you can figure out how to place the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Write **Media Query** click below link for better understanding.
```

Example

```
/* Mobile Styles */
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
 body {
   /* Change the alignment Here (**Write css** here for Mobile)*/
 }
}
/* Tablet Styles */
@media only screen and (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 960px) {
 body {
   /* Change the alignment Here (**Write css** here for Tablet)*/
 }
}
/* Desktop Styles */
@media only screen and (min-width: 961px) {
 body {
   /* Change the alignment Here (**Write css** here for Desktop)*/
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, I ended up using WordPress with element or and I also used media queries so I'll accept this as the answer.